# Angular Ionic Geolocation App

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I need to write an application that will run in the background on Android and IOS that delivery drivers can run on their phones.  This application will simply get the driver's current location and send that to our web server every five minutes or so.  I wrote this type of app before just as an HTML5 app that ran in a web browser on the phone but of course the minute the driver closes their web browser or moves to a new page in their browser the app stopped working.  Would this be different / better as an Angular Ionic app so that it could run in the background without interruption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It would definitely be better to run as a hybrid app.

I would recommend this 3h course on Pluralsight website.

http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/building-mobile-apps-ionic-framework-angularjs

It covers GeoLocation, data & caching, mapping and more.